# XSLT Transform to use multiple children elements to process parent elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to use XSLT to manage the processing of validation within an application. I have tried numerous methods including defining template matches and iterating through the sets of attributes within the schema. Here is a sample input file that contains Validation elements which define what should be done to the Parent element attributes that they are descendants of.

Example..

## XML Input

```
<PartyDefinition Suffix="" Religion="" Race="" PrimaryLanguage="" Prefix="" MiddleName="" LastName="Zztestpw" Gender="Female" FirstName="Ghlab" Ethnicity="" Degree="" DeathDate="" BirthDate="19670707000000">
    <Validation ProductCode="eHARS VL" Extra3="" Extra2="" Extra1="" Element="PartyDefinition" Effect="Remove Attribute" Cause="Lookup Value Empty" Attribute="Race" Action="No Action"/>
    <Validation ProductCode="eHARS VL" Extra3="" Extra2="" Extra1="5" Element="PartyDefinition" Effect="Truncate Field" Cause="Field exceeded size limit" Attribute="LastName" Action="No Action">Zztestpw</Validation>
    <Validation ProductCode="eHARS VL" Extra3="" Extra2="" Extra1=""  Element="PartyDefinition" Effect="Remove Attribute" Cause="Lookup Value Empty" Attribute="Ethnicity" Action="No Action"/>
    <ExternalIDDefinition ExternalIDType="MR" ExternalID="2144448"/>
    <ExternalIDDefinition ExternalIDType="PI" ExternalID="3932558"/>
    <ExternalIDDefinition ExternalIDType="" ExternalID=""/>
</PartyDefinition>
```

1. For the effect "Remove Attribute" the corresponding Attribute in the Parent should be removed
2. For the effect "Truncate Attribute" the corresponding Attribute in the Parent should be truncated to Extra1 characters

## XML Ouput

```
<PartyDefinition Suffix="" Religion="" PrimaryLanguage="" Prefix="" MiddleName="" LastName="Zztes" Gender="Female" FirstName="Ghlab" Degree="" DeathDate="" BirthDate="19670707000000">
    <ExternalIDDefinition ExternalIDType="MR" ExternalID="2144448"/>
    <ExternalIDDefinition ExternalIDType="PI" ExternalID="3932558"/>
    <ExternalIDDefinition ExternalIDType="" ExternalID=""/>
</PartyDefinition>
```

1. The LastName attribute was truncated to 5 characters
2. The Race and Ethnicity attributes were removed

**Thank you for any direction!**

Comment: Please show at least one of the numerous ways that you have tried. That makes it easier to point out where you went wrong.

Comment: It's kind of unfortunate that you edited out the attributes you defined rules for.

Comment: *"The Race and Ethnicity attributes were removed"* As noted by @MathiasMüller, the question in its present form makes no sense, because these attributes weren't there in the first place. Also, please clarify if there can be *other* elements which may carry `<Validation>` children that need processing.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I've rolled back the edit so it should now make sense again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual for this sort of "make a few changes to the original" stylesheet, you should start with an identity transformation

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

which will produce a duplicate of the input.  Now start adding templates for the things you want to change.  You want to remove the Validation elements:

```
<xsl:template match="Validation" />
```

and for a `PartyDefinition` you want to follow the rules that those elements defined:

```
<xsl:template match="PartyDefinition">
  <!-- save for reference inside the for-each -->
  <xsl:variable name="party" select="." />
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each select="Validation[@Effect='Truncate Field']">
      <xsl:attribute name="{@Attribute}">
        <!-- truncate original value -->
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($party/@*[local-name() = current()/@Attribute], 1, @Extra1)" />
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <!-- include all attributes that aren't covered by validation rules -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(current()/Validation/@Attribute = local-name())]" />
    <!-- and process all children -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Here I'm only processing the "truncate" rules explicitly - the "remove" rules are catered for by the fact that I ignore any attribute that was covered by a validation rule.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. I am in a meeting currently will test shortly.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the `Race` and `Ethnicity` attributes are still present after the transformation.

Comment: @MathiasMüller They shouldn't be - I don't copy attributes that match _any_ validation rule, and I don't do anything at all for "remove" rules.  Those two facts should combine to suppress the `Race` and `Ethnicity` attributes.

Comment: <!-- include all attributes that aren't covered by validation rules -->
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(Validation/@Attribute = local-name())]" /> Overwrites the changes previously made

Comment: @user2920540 Oops, missing a `current()` there.

Comment: Excellent..That was the key!

Comment: @user2920540 If this solves your problem, please accept it as an answer (mark the tick on the left).

Comment: New to this area. Thanks again for all your support!